# rellenar un dataframe con valores de otro

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo este Dataframe, que es de valores nulos que no se han rellenado bien.

```
      Unidad  Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos  \
49          1    1000    Gasolina            1998.0      50.0   
63          1     800    Gasolina            1998.0      50.0   
88          1     600    Gasolina            1999.0      54.0   
107         1    3100      Diésel            2008.0      54.0   
244         1    2000      Diésel            1995.0      60.0   
...       ...     ...         ...               ...       ...   
46609       1   47795    Gasolina            2016.0     420.0   
46770       1   26900    Gasolina            2011.0     450.0   
46936       1   19900    Gasolina            2007.0     510.0   
46941       1   24500    Gasolina            2006.0     514.0   
47128       1   79600    Gasolina            2017.0     612.0   

      Comunidad_autonoma         Marca_y_Modelo Año_Venta       Año_Comunidad  \
49        Islas Baleares             CITROEN AX      2020  2020Islas Baleares   
63        Islas Baleares             SEAT Arosa      2021  2021Islas Baleares   
88        Islas Baleares          FIAT Seicento      2020  2020Islas Baleares   
107             La Rioja            TOYOTA Aygo      2020        2020La Rioja   
244               Aragón            PEUGEOT 205      2019          2019Aragón   
...                  ...                    ...       ...                 ...   
46609           La Rioja        PORSCHE Cayenne      2020        2020La Rioja   
46770           Cataluña               AUDI RS5      2020        2020Cataluña   
46936     Islas Baleares  MERCEDES-BENZ Clase M      2020  2020Islas Baleares   
46941           La Rioja  MERCEDES-BENZ Clase E      2020        2020La Rioja   
47128     Islas Baleares  MERCEDES-BENZ Clase E      2021  2021Islas Baleares   

           Fecha  Año  Super_95  Diesel Comunidad Salario en euros anuales  
49    2020-12-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
63    2021-01-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
88    2020-12-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
107   2020-12-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
244   2019-03-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
...          ...  ...       ...     ...       ...                      ...  
46609 2020-12-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
46770 2020-07-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
46936 2020-10-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
46941 2020-11-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN  
47128 2021-01-01  NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN                      NaN
```

necesito complear las tablas de gasolina, diesel y salario con los valores de las siguientes:

```
     Año  Super_95    Diesel Comunidad Año_Comunidad      Fecha  \
0    2020  1.321750  1.246000   Navarra   2020Navarra 2020-01-01   
1    2020  1.301000  1.207250   Navarra   2020Navarra 2020-02-01   
2    2020  1.224800  1.126200   Navarra   2020Navarra 2020-03-01   
3    2020  1.106667  1.020000   Navarra   2020Navarra 2020-04-01   
4    2020  1.078750  0.986250   Navarra   2020Navarra 2020-05-01   
..    ...       ...       ...       ...           ...        ...   
386  2021  1.416600  1.265000  La rioja  2021La rioja 2021-08-01   
387  2021  1.431000  1.277000  La rioja  2021La rioja 2021-09-01   
388  2021  1.474000  1.344000  La rioja  2021La rioja 2021-10-01   
389  2021  1.510200  1.382000  La rioja  2021La rioja 2021-11-01   
390  2021  1.481333  1.348667  La rioja  2021La rioja 2021-12-01   

    Salario en euros anuales  
0                  27.995,96  
1                  27.995,96  
2                  27.995,96  
3                  27.995,96  
4                  27.995,96  
..                       ...  
386                21.535,29  
387                21.535,29  
388                21.535,29  
389                21.535,29  
390                21.535,29
```

Seria rellenar las columnas del primero con el segundo cuando la tabla año_comunidad coincida. por ejemplo en los nan donde aparezca 2020Islas Baleares en la misma fila. que rellene con el valor del precio de la gasolina de la otra tabla donde apararezca 2020Islas Baleares en la misma fila. en el caso que sea 2020aragon, sería con 2020 aragon y así.
Había pensado algún cogido así:

```
analisis['Super_95'].fillna(analisis2['Super_95'].apply(lambda x: x if x=='2020Islas Baleares' else np.nan), inplace=True)
```

pero no me funciona.

Comment: Buen día, he visto que has puesto varias preguntas relacionadas a los mismos datos y hasta ahora varios usuarios han podido ayudarte, lo que me intriga es ¿Qué es lo que esperas hacer de principio a fin? Porque como no conocemos lo que deseas hacer tal vez ir armando tu código con partes de diferentes respuestas está haciendo un código tipo monstruo de Frankestein (Pedazos de código medio adaptados entre sí) He votado positivamente en tu pregunta para que tengas accesso al chat.

Comment: He creado una [sala](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250065/rellenar-un-dataframe-con-valores-de-otro) para que podamos platicar ahí sobre lo que deseas hacer, tal vez hay alguna forma de optimizar el código que tienes y obtener el resultado esperado.

Comment: Cuando tenga un poco más de tiempo redacto una respuesta sobre esta pregunta, pero creo que este problema surge de juntar las respuestas anteriores a tus otras preguntas, por eso cree la sala de chat para poder revisar lo que deseas hacer.